# When was the Holy Ghost given? After or before the resurrection?

Tags: contradiction

**After the ressurrection**:

- The Holy Ghost was not yet given; because that Jesus was not yet glorified. [John 7:39](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%207&version=ESV)
- And when he had said this, he breathed on them, and saith unto them, Receive ye the Holy Ghost. [John 20:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+20&version=ESV)
- And when the day of Pentecost was fully come, they were all with one accord in one place. And suddenly there came a sound from heaven as of a rushing mighty wind, and it filled all the house where they were sitting. And there appeared unto them cloven tongues like as of fire, and it sat upon each of them. And they were all filled with the Holy Ghost, and began to speak with other tongues, as the Spirit gave them utterance. [Acts 2:1-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%202&version=ESV)

**Before the resurrection:**

- For David himself said by the Holy Ghost, The LORD said to my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, till I make thine enemies thy footstool. [Mark 12:36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%2012&version=ESV)
- ... which the Holy Ghost by the mouth of David spake.... [Acts 1:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%201&version=ESV)
- Elisabeth was filled with the Holy Ghost. [Luke 1:41](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%201&version=ESV)

How can these accounts be reconciled?

Comment: The Holy Spirit was  breathed (by the Lord) on the chosen eleven. Thereafter, the Holy Spirit was shed abroad, in connection with the apostolic gospel made known by those eleven (soon to be twelve). Individually, the ministrations of the Holy Spirit were experienced by certain persons, but not corporately. The question needs to take in the aspect of the Body of Christ and the anointing of the whole body, from the Head downwards, as typified in the Aaronic priesthood, see Psalm 134, the head, the beard and to the skirts of the garments. But up-voted +1 in the hope of more clarity.

Comment: Hi Black Watch, welcome to BH.SE, thanks for contributing! You've added a number of questions today that don't show any evidence of prior research and aren't very focused. Please do take more time and care ensuring that your questions are clear and you've actually made some effort at investigation first - most of these topics you're interested in have been covered many times over by similar questions.

Comment: Hi @SteveTaylor, what do you mean by "prior research"? Searching similar questions on StackExchange? Or showing what research I did online that made me come up with the question?

Comment: All prophets are believed to have predicted future events by the aid of the Holy Ghost indwelling them, as is plainly stated in the well-known Nicene creed, recited each Sunday; they certainly did not guess them all by themselves(!). However, prophets were few and far in between, and so were miracle-workers (such as Moses, Elijah, or Elisha); by contrast, in the apostolic era, the New Testament speaks of an unprecedented outpouring of God's Spirit to the early Christian community, to the extent to which previously rare events now became the norm.

Comment: @Lucian, but that won't explain the lack of real prophets, if the Holy Ghost gives us supernatural powers to predict the future and cure diseases, then he doesn't do much on modern day. There must be a different explanation.

Comment: @BlackWatch: It is plain to anyone reading the book of Acts, or even some passages of Paul's letters, that there seems to have been a (reported) increase in prophecies, miracles, and speaking in tongues, unlike anything previously mentioned elsewhere in scripture; now, whether or to what extent the reports are true, or whether they were meant to continue indefinitely, etc. are different questions.

Comment: @Lucian I addressed the **modern day**.

Comment: @BlackWatch: Were the writers of the texts you mentioned also doing the same ? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129489/discussion-between-black-watch-and-lucian).